# Why am I getting an undefined method error in rails 4 with this simple create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, undefined, rails-activerecord, simple-form

I have found some similar questions on stack overflow, but nothing that helps.  I have a user model.  I have a profile model that belongs to the user model.  I have a job model that belongs to the profile model.  I am making a simple form to create a job.  When i submit the form in the browser, I am given the error:

```
undefined method `build_job' for #<Student:0x007f8309023530>
```

And it shows the create action in the jobs controller:

```
def create
    job = current_user.build_job(job_params)
    job.save
    redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile_name)
end
```

The jobs create method is identical to the profiles create method, with the word profile replaced with job, so I can't figure out why its not working.  My guess is it has something to do with jobs belonging to a model that belongs to another model.  How do I fix this?  Also, here is the job_params method:

```
def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:title, :category, :description, :state, :zip_code, :rate, jobs_attributes: [:firm, :position])
end
```

And here are my models:

Job:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

Profile:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :jobs, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile
end
```

Reference in view:

```
<%= @user.profile.job.firm if @user.profile.try(:job)%>
```

I am also adding my server log from clicking on submit.  Hope it helps answer the question:

```
  Started POST "/jobs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-27 21:45:06 -0400
    ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  Processing by JobsController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VRqIuzR1x6tE/G+/wzrG1iFBOEDE7mgsfyjokX7wNZo=", "job"=>{"firm"=>"signat", "position"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save"}
    User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
     (0.2ms)  BEGIN
    SQL (3.4ms)  INSERT INTO "jobs" ("created_at", "firm", "position", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 28 Oct 2013 01:45:06 UTC +00:00], ["firm", "signat"], ["position", ""], ["updated_at", Mon, 28 Oct 2013 01:45:06 UTC +00:00]]
     (0.4ms)  COMMIT
  Redirected to http://localhost:3000/profiles/philip7899
  Completed 302 Found in 209ms (ActiveRecord: 9.8ms)


  Started GET "/profiles/philip7899" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-27 21:45:06 -0400
  Processing by ProfilesController#show as HTML
    Parameters: {"id"=>"philip7899"}
    User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
    User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."profile_name" = 'philip7899' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
    Profile Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
    School Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "schools".* FROM "schools" WHERE "schools"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "schools"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
    Job Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."profile_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["profile_id", 1]]
    Rendered profiles/_full_profile.html.erb (92.4ms)
    Rendered profiles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (95.4ms)
    Rendered layouts/_ssi_header_inner.html.erb (4.2ms)
    Rendered layouts/_ssi_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 218ms (Views: 209.4ms | ActiveRecord: 5.9ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems. You need to define `has_many` jobs on user, and the correct method for building `has_many` is `association.build` not `build_association`:

```
class User
  has_many :jobs, through: :profile
end

job = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)
```

Comment: Thanks, that got the form to not make an error upon submission but i still get the same error (well, almost.  undefined method 'job') when I refer to jobs in my view.  I realized I forgot to post the reference in the view - I will do that now.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just posted the line from the view.

Comment: @Philip7899 that's because your profile `has_many` jobs but you're referencing `profile.job`. You'll have to loop through the `profiles.jobs` array. If you only want to show the last job: `@user.profile.jobs.last.firm if @user.profile.jobs.any?`.

Comment: Thanks, its not showing the firm in the view though.  It's just blank?  I put in your code so it should show the last job's firm.

Comment: @Philip7899 I couldn't say what the problem is without the code. Are you seeing errors in the server log?

Comment: I don't see any errors but it is confusing to read.  I am putting it in the main question content above.  I think it has something to do with either not posting it correctly

Comment: @Philip7899 from your server log it looks as if your `jobs` table doesn't have a `profile_id` column, or the association is not being passed when saved. Try `current_user.profile.jobs.build`. If the problem persists, could you output your `jobs` table schema? If a `Job` requires an associated `Profile`, then I'd add a validation to be sure (in your `Job` model): `validates :profile, presence: true`.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Do all models nested within models nested within models need to have a through relationship?

Comment: @Philip7899 not necessarily. The `through` is mainly used as a helpful alias to those nested models. It really depends on how your forms are structured. For example, if a user form has a nested jobs array, then yes, it will require a `has_many jobs, through: :profile`, and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs`. As I say, aside from that, it is mainly used for easy access.